# ERRO GAPI Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Migrei o projeto de hospedagem e utilizando a classe *GAPI* em *PHP* para coletar informações do *Google Analytics*, não funciona no novo servidor reportando o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "GDataauthErrorAuthorizationInvalid Credentials"' in

Como se as credenciais de login estivessem erradas. Porem o mesmo teste em localhost funciona perfeitamente. Alguém sabe me falar se é algum recurso no servidor de hospedagem que precisa ser habilitado? se sim sabem me falar qual? pois os dados de login estão corretos.